# PHP output json web service

Tags: php, json, web-services

I am very new to the PHP, I am coming from the background of .net. I am trying to make web service which will take parameter from URL and process business logic then output it in jSON.

This is my code

```
<?php
    $data = '';
    $Site = $_GET['COUNTRY_SITE'];
    $Language = $_GET['LANGUAGE'];

    $data = "{\"Site\":" . "\"" . $Site . "\"" . ",\"Language\":" . "\"" . $Language . "\"" . "}";
    //header('Content-type: application/json');
    //echo $data;
    $x =  json_decode($data,true);
    var_dump($x);

?>
```

I am getting below output

```
array(2) {
  ["Site"]=>
  string(5) "India"
  ["Language"]=>
  string(2) "GB"
}
```

Why I am not getting output like this

```
{
"Site":"India",
"Language":"GB"
}
```

Can somebody help me and do explain if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are manually creating a JSON and then decode it. The output can be expected, in fact. I think you should use PHP tools to convert your object to JSON:

```
<?php
    $data = '';
    $Site = $_GET['COUNTRY_SITE'];
    $Language = $_GET['LANGUAGE'];

    //Associative array
    $data = array("Site" => $Site, "Language" => $Language);    

    $x =  json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    var_dump($x);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace 
`var_dump($x);` to `echo $x =  json_encode(json_decode($data,true),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

**Notes:**

1. `json_decode($data,true)` This will output an array.
2. `json_encode(json_decode($data,true),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` This will change array into json format in pretty view

**Output:**

```
{
    "Site": "s",
    "Language": "ss"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $data = '';
    $Site = $_GET['COUNTRY_SITE'];
    $Language = $_GET['LANGUAGE'];

    $data = "{\"Site\":" . "\"" . $Site . "\"" . ",\"Language\":" . "\"" . $Language . "\"" . "}";
    //header('Content-type: application/json');
    //echo $data;
    $x =  json_encode(json_decode($data,true),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    var_dump($x);

?>
```

If you want dynamic JSON result:

```
<?php
echo json_encode($_GET,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're echoing out is a php array based on the JSON string you built, $data.

However you should reverse your flow and build a php array and then use json_encode() to build the string for you. This will ensure the json is always formatted correctly.

```
<?php
$data = [
  'Site' => $_GET['COUNTRY_SITE'],
  'Language' => $_GET['LANGUAGE']
];

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

The JSON_PRETTY_PRINT option will format it with spaces so that it's more pleasant to read but you can remove it to condense the output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<?php
    $data = '';
    $Site = $_GET['COUNTRY_SITE'];
    $Language = $_GET['LANGUAGE'];
    $data =array('Site'=>$Site,'Language'=>$Language);

    header('Content-type: application/json');

    $x =  json_encode($data);
    var_dump($x);

?>
```